# SimpleDateFormat parse returns wrong value

Tags: java, parsing, java-7, simpledateformat

I have this code:

```
public static String formatMinSecOrHourMinSec(final String length) {
        try {
            final SimpleDateFormat hhmmss = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.GERMAN);
            final Date date = hhmmss.parse(length);
            final GregorianCalendar gc0 = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.GERMAN);
            gc0.setTime(date);
            if(gc0.getTimeInMillis() >= 3600 * 1000){
                return hhmmss.format(gc0.getTime());
            }else{
                final SimpleDateFormat mmss = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss");
                return mmss.format(gc0.getTime());                    
            }
        } catch (final ParseException e) {
            LOGGER.debug("Konnte die Länge nicht parsen: " + length + "\n" + e);
            return length;
        }
    }
```

I estimate that it returns **01:29:00** if `length` is set to **01:29:00** but it returns **29:00**. This is because `gc0.getTimeInMillis()` returns one hour less (3600 * 1000) than  expected. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: gc0.getTimeInMillis() returns one hour less (3600 * 1000) than expected.

so according to your statement your condition is false and what you get is correct.

Comment: You may or may not also have an issue with timezones.  You are loading the time in the `Locale.German`, but the time in millis will be returned as an offset relative to midnight 1-1-1970 UTC (GMT), this could potentially be the cause of an unexpected hour offset but is certainly something you need to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because java.util.Date is using your default time zone. (print time in ms from `date` and you will see).
To fix it try:

```
final SimpleDateFormat hhmmss = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
hhmmss.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Do not conflate a span-of-time with a time-of-day. Two different concepts deserve two different classes. A span-of-time is represented by the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) (or `Period`) class.

```
Duration
.ofHours( 1 )
.plusMinutes( 29 )
```

…or…

```
Duration
.parse( "PT1H29M" )
```

## Wrong classes

First, you are using inappropriate classes. Apparently you are trying to track a span-of-time but are using time-of-day to do so. A span and a time are two different concepts. Mixing the two leads to ambiguity, confusion, and errors.

Second, you are using terrible old classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. Never use `SimpleDateFormat`, `GregorianCalendar`, etc.

## Span-of-time

The correct class for a span-of-time in the range of hours-minutes-seconds is `Duration`. For a range of years-months-days, use `Period`.

You can instantiate your `Duration` from numbers of hours and minutes.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 1 ).plusMinutes( 29 ) ;
```

Or you can parse a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, [`PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

```
Duration d = Duration.parse( "PT1H29M" ) ;
```

## Date-Time math

You can do math with date-time values. Perhaps you want to know when is an hour and twenty-nine minutes from now.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ; // Capture the current moment as seen though the wall-clock time used by the people of some particular region.
ZonedDateTime later = now.plus( d ) ;  // Add a span-of-time to determine a later moment (or an earlier moment if the `Duration` is negative).
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).